# XQUERY SQL - How to pass individual node element(s) as variables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, xquery-sql

Is there an alternate way to pass node elements *dynamically* than the one shown below - ?

```
select XMLTable.XMLCOL.query('//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@node")')
```

For e.g., even if I am trying to give the fully qualified path, I do not want to hard code the node elements, instead I would like to pass them individually as parameters.

Under the section -

**Example: Query Using sp_executesql**

@ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345118(v=sql.90).aspx

it says -

> query contains wildcards (*) and node tests using node names and is
> hard to optimize well. Consequently, it performs much worse than the
> original query and the query construction approach.

Answer (score 0):

May be like this:

```
declare @qry nvarchar(1000)
set @qry = 'select XMLCOL.query(''//' + @node + ''') from XMLTable'
exec( @qry )
```